# clear textbox after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which posts using ajax and reloads the div underneath.

I need the textbox to clear when the submit button is pressed.

```
<form name=goform action="" method=post>
<textarea name=comment></textarea>
<input type=submit value=submit>
</form>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add an `id` for the `textarea`.

```
<textarea name='comment' id='comment'></textarea>
```

Hook into the submit process and add:

```
$('#comment').val('');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using jQuery (which is required for the solutions given above) you can replace the

```
$("#txtComment").val("");
```

with

```
document.getElementById("txtComment").value = "";
```

Comment: oh, just realized the question was tagged with "jquery" so probably you are using it :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply call this after posting:

```
$("textarea[name=comment]").val("");
```

Or to improve, assign an ID to your textarea:

```
<form name=goform action="" method=post>
<textarea id="txtComment" name="comment"></textarea>
<input type=submit value=submit>
</form>
```

and use this after posting:

```
$("#txtComment").val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function testSubmit()
    {
        var x = document.forms["myForm"]["input1"];
        var y = document.forms["myForm"]["input2"];
        if (x.value === "")
        {
            alert(' fill!!');
            return false;
        } Blockquote
        if(y.value === "")
        {
            alert('plz fill the!!');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function submitForm()
    {
        if (testSubmit())
        {
            document.forms["myForm"].submit(); //first submit
            document.forms["myForm"].reset(); //and then reset the form values
        }
    } </script> <body>
    <form method="get" name="myForm">

        First Name: <input type="text" name="input1"/>
        <br/>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="input2"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()"/>
    </form>

</body>
```